# My grails project facing error"TransactionRequiredException:no transaction" using domain.save(flush:true).save() it can is saving but updating

Tags: java, spring, grails, flush

```
package com.fhjony.ocbt


import grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap


class MemberService {

def save(GrailsParameterMap params) {
    Member member = new Member(params)
    def response = AppUtil.saveResponse(false, member)
    if (member.validate()) {
        member.save(true)
        if (!member.hasErrors()){
            response.isSuccess = true
        }
    }
    return response
}


def update(Member member, GrailsParameterMap params) {

    member.properties = params
    def response = AppUtil.saveResponse(false, member)
    if (member.validate()) {
        member.save(flush: true)
        if (!member.hasErrors()){
            response.isSuccess = true
        }
    }
    return response
}


def getById(Serializable id) {
    return Member.get(id)
}


def list(GrailsParameterMap params) {
    params.max = params.max ?: GlobalConfig.itemPerPage()
    List<Member> memberList = Member.createCriteria().list(params) {
        if (params?.colName && params?.colValue) {
            like(params.colName, "%" + params.colValue + "%")
        }
        if (!params.sort) {
            order("id", "desc")
        }
    }
    return [list: memberList, count: memberList.totalCount]
}


def delete(Member member) {
    try {

        member.delete(flush: true,failOnError:true)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println(e.getMessage())
        return false
    }
    return true
}
}
```

**Error message:**

```
URI /member/update Class
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException Message null Caused by
no transaction is in progress
     Line | Method
 ->>  211 | invoke           in org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |    188 | invoke           in org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass |     90 | handle . . . .
 . in org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter |   1039
 | doDispatch       in
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet |    942 | doService
 . . .  in     '' |   1005 | processRequest   in
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet |    908 | doPost . .
 . . . in     '' |    882 | service          in     '' |     77 |
 doFilterInternal in
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll get more help if you go to the Help Center (see the question mark on the upper right) to learn how to create a good title and question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your database interactions to be happening in a transactional context.  One simple piece of that is you can mark your service class with `@grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional`.

Separate from that, and this isn't really related to your question, but passing `GrailsParameterMap` map around as a method argument is an unusual thing to do.  What the right thing to do is depends on some factors in your app and you may want to pass values into your service rather than the whole map but if you really want the whole map in the service, one way to get there is by way of `WebAttributes`.

```
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import grails.web.api.WebAttributes

@Transactional
class MemberService implements WebAttributes {

    def serviceMethod() {
        // you can access params here because 
        // WebAttributes provides access to it
        Member member = new Member(params)

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Jeff, thank you for taking the time to help others. One doubt, as a general practice, we should not access the request/response (i.e. web layer) in the services, right?

Comment: If you were following uncle Bob, you would definitely keep your web classes, or I/O on the outer layer. https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html